# How to use Javascript in Spyder IDE?

Tags: javascript, python, spyder

I want to use write code in Javascript, in the Spyder IDE, that is meant for Python. I have read that Spyder supports multiple languages but I'm not sure how to use it. I have downloaded Nodejs and added it to the environment variables. I'd like to know how get Javascript syntax colouring, possibly auto-completion and Help options as well ,and I'd also like to know how to conveniently execute the `.js` file and see the results in a console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Sorry but for now we only support Python for all the functionality that you are looking for (code completion, help and code execution).

Our next major version (Spyder 4, to be released later in 2019) will have the ability to give code completion and linting for other programming languages, but it'll be more of a power-user feature than something anyone can use.

Comment: Are the features available in the pre-release?

Comment: Yes, they are. But you need to setup a completion server by hand in `Tools > Preferences > Completion and linting > Other languages`.